# Как правильно сделать верстку кнопки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, button, sass

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-phone" href="#"><span>+11 235 813 2134</span></a>
```

SASS:

```
.btn
  padding: 10px 34px
  display: inline-block
  color: $dark
  border-radius: 10px
  text-decoration: none
  &-phone
    background-color: $active-color
    &:hover
      background-color: lighten($active-color, 4%)
    span
      border-bottom: 1px dashed $dark
      &:hover
        border-bottom: none
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать верстку, чтобы при наведение на кнопку, подчеркивание у текста пропадало?
Сейчас подчеркивание пропадает только, если навести на элемент `<span>` и он занимает не все место кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```css
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn span {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black
}

.btn:hover span{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-phone" href="#"><span>+11 235 813 2134</span></a>
```

SASS:

```
.btn
     padding: 10px
     background: yellow
     text-decoration: none
     span
          border-bottom: 1px dashed black
     &:hover span
          border-bottom: none
```